# Override Apache method access settings

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4, .htaccess

My website located at hosting server with Apache2/PHP5. When I published my site i found that on some server returns 403 Forbidden. I found that this error appears on request with method PUT and DELETE.
I do not have access to the httpd.conf and i can't check out settings, but i have .htaccess file:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Can I modify the file to override server settings and give access to PUT and DELETE requests?

Answer (score 0):

You should check first what's blocking PUT and DELETE. This could be a Firewall rule.

To modify the settings and allow the blocked method:

```
<LimitExcept POST GET DELETE PUT>
   #Require valid user
   Require all granted
</LimitExcept>
```

Refer to [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html)